# How do I clean up packages that have been purged that are still showing up on "apt get update" command?

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, software-updates

I am still learning linux and have been running into a slight issue with my Raspbian OS system. I have uninstalled software like docker and vs code to clear up memory for my OMV NAS; however, they still show up when I run apt-get update. To be clear, everything is functioning properly. I have already tried the following commands: apt-get clean, apt-get autoremove, and reboot. I would like to clean up this part if at all possible. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: The remove all that also takes out related not in use dependencies. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The command `apt-get update` reads from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.  It updates the repository cache, so your machine knows what packages are available from those repositories.

To remove any of these repositories, you would need to remove them from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or they could also be configured in any file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.  Check they are removed by running `apt-get update` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your sources.list as follows (raspbian Buster):

remove everything under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then create `raspi.list`:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

create `raspi.list`:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` using the following command:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

To install OMV use the [installation script](https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/installScript):

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/installScript/master/install | sudo bash
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This did the trick. I also see now that I need to reinstall OMV, as it did not install correctly the first time. But this got rid of docker and visual studio code for me.

Comment: @Brent I have edited my answer to include OMV install.

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R. This is not related to the post, but after many failed attempts to correctly configure OMV I tried out Samba instead. This process was so much easier to set up on the Raspbian OS.